# NSThread is blocking my GUI

Tags: iphone, user-interface, nsthread

I use a `NSThread` in order to download videos and images from a server side.It work looks and works great except the fact that when the downloading is done my `GUI` gets blocked until the download is complete.When the download is finished it takes a few seconds to work again.

this is how the server request is done:

```
- (void) repeatRequest{
    NSLog(@"repeatRequest");
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(backgroundRequest) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void) backgroundRequest{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myURLStr];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

    [pool drain];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    //do things
}
```

IMPORTANTAnd I also tried to start the `ASIHTTPRequest` from the `GUI thread` but with the same behaviour.

Any idea about what could be wrong?

EDIT:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    //internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];

    if(timer1 == nil)
    {
        timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector: @selector(repeatRequest) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: where you are calling repeatRequest, can you specify ?

Comment: I edited my question with code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run synchronous ASIHTTPRequest in your background thread, and handle results not in delegate method (requestFinished), but after  [request startSynchronous];

Comment: and handle results not in delegate method (requestFinished), but after [request startSynchronous]; how to do this?Please tell...:)

Comment: Replase `[request startAsynchronous];` with `[request startSynchronous];` and after `[request startSynchronous];` line do things what you want to do in `- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request`

Comment: should I delete the request finished method?And also delete this line:[request setDelegate:self];???Thank you:)

Comment: ok it is working.But please telll me what is the explanation of this?Why is different from what I did.Thank you

Comment: You can remove `[request setDelegate:self]`

Comment: Explanation: you want to run `backgroundRequest` method in background, then you run `ASIHTTPRequest` in background too, this is not right. This way you got 2 background threads.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about `ASIHTTPRequest` but i would assume its `-startAsynchronous` method already handles the background downloading for you. It all likelihood, it is returning immediately and your new thread is exiting. Also, you should just use `[pool release]` at the end of a thread method instead of `[pool drain]`, it will be drained upon release, and you won't be leaking an `NSAutoReleasePool`. Does `ASIHTTPRequest` have a `-startSynchronous` (or just plain `-start`) method? Try using that within `-backgroundRequest`, as it should block the premature exit of that thread.

Comment: This is wrong. -drain "releases and pops the receiver". http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Well I used -startSynchronous method with the thread and it has trhe same behaviour.And as I said in the IMPORTANT part of the question...i already tried to start the request asynchronous from the GUI thread but stilll not working!